# flex remove buttons border from toggle button bar

Tags: apache-flex, border, togglebuttonbar

how to remove the border of a togglebuttonbar button, with keeping the theme color??

i want to put the style in css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should us the following style:

```
.myButtonStyle
{
    skin: ClassReference("mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove the border on a button by creating a button skin.

Once you have that skin, you can use the ToggleButtonBar's [buttonStyleName](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/mx/controls/ButtonBar.html#style:buttonStyleName) style to modify the styling of the buttons in the bar.  Also check out [firstbuttonStyleName](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/mx/controls/ButtonBar.html#style:firstButtonStyleName) and [lastButtonStyleName](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/mx/controls/ButtonBar.html#style:lastButtonStyleName).